# Creating an rtf custom mail item

Tags: c#, rtf, outlook-redemption

I'm using redemption to create a custom mail item and save it in the draft folder of my outlook. Currently the mailItem is saved in HTML format. I want to be able to save it in rtf Format. How can I do that ?

Here is the code I am using :

```
 Redemption.RDOSession session = new Redemption.RDOSession();
 session.MAPIOBJECT = olApp.Session.MAPIOBJECT;
 Redemption.RDOFolder rFolder = session.GetDefaultFolder(Redemption.rdoDefaultFolders.olFolderDrafts);
 Redemption.RDOMail rMsg = rFolder.Items.Add("ipm.note.mep");
 // modify some custom fields ...
 rMsg.BodyFormat = 3;
 rMsg.Save();

 Outlook.MailItem oMep = olApp.Session.GetItemFromID(rMsg.EntryID);
 oMep.BodyFormat = Outlook.OlBodyFormat.olFormatRichText;
 oMep.Display(false);
```

Changing the bodyFormat doesn't seem to work. I also tried the saveAs method with no success. I can change the format manually when the mailItem is open, but I want to do that automatically within my C# code.

Comment: Why do you need to use Redemption to create an Outlook items? Did you try to automate Outlook instead? Do you get the same results?

Comment: I need to use the Redemption api to modify some custom fields without having the security popup.

Comment: [Using Redemption Objects](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/objects.htm)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Have you tried to set the `RDOMail.RtfBody` property?

Comment: This is really more of a comment than an answer.

Comment: No, it is an answer, sorry John. This is a polite way of saying "You really need to set the RDOMail.RtfBody property for Outlook to consider your message to be in the RTF format".

Comment: Changing the RtfBody property of the RDOMailItem did not work. The body was never updated to the new value. But by changing the RtfBody of the OutlookMailItem, I was able to change the body format of my mailItem. See code below:

`System.Text.Encoding encoding = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();     
byte[] rtfBodyBytes = encoding.GetBytes("{}");
oMep.RTFBody = rtfBodyBytes;`

Comment: Did you save the message after setting the RtfBody property?